# Snapchat camera button

Tags: android, button, onclick, gesture, ontouch

i'm making a button that works like the snapchat camera button with choice to either click or press and hold/release.

click - print tap

press and hold - hold and on release print - release

tap work perfectly but ontouch never gets call. i really need help with this please thanks.

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

private Button TouchMe;
private GestureDetector gesture;
private boolean isSpeakButtonLongPressed = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TouchMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
   gesture = new GestureDetector(this,new Gesture());
    TouchMe.setOnTouchListener(this);

}


class Gesture extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener implements View.OnTouchListener{

    private boolean mIsLongpressEnabled = false;

    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent ev) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent ev) {

        }


    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                            float distanceY) {

        return false;

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDown (MotionEvent event) {

        return false;
    }

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                           float velocityY) {

        if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            return false; // Right to left
        }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            return false; // Left to right
        }

        if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            return false;
        }  else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            return false; // Top to bottom
        }
        return false;
    }


    public void setIsLongpressEnabled(boolean isLongpressEnabled) {
        mIsLongpressEnabled = isLongpressEnabled;
    }
    public boolean isLongpressEnabled() {
        return mIsLongpressEnabled;
    }


    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev){
        if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            handel.postDelayed(run, 2000);
            return true;
        }else if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            handel.removeCallbacks(run);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "release!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        };
        return true;
    }
    Handler handel = new Handler();

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            handel.postDelayed(run, 2000);
            return true;
        }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            handel.removeCallbacks(run);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "release!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        };

        return  gesture.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }
}



    Runnable run = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your code to run on long click
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hold", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

     gesture.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return `false` from `onDown()`, the system assumes that you want to ignore the rest of the gesture, and the other methods of GestureDetector.OnGestureListener never get called. This has the potential to cause unexpected problems in your app. The only time you should return `false` from `onDown()` is if you truly want to ignore an entire gesture.

Actually, I advise you to create subclass for your button where you can override `dispatchTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` and handle you gesture. It will allow to simplify your activity class and re-use component. Also it's a good idea to create your callback interface for actions like onTapHold, onTapRelease, etc.

Hope you manage to solve it!

Comment: if i return true on the onDown() section...it still work the same as if it is false.    i dont know how to go from creatin onTapHold or onTapRelease...